# How do I reduce the delay when unlocking my Mac?

Tags: mac, mojave, login

There is a ~1 second delay every time I input my password to unlock the Mac, regardless if it is correct or not. I'd like to turn this off, or at least reduce it. How can I do this?

Comment: This just sounds like normal behavior to be honest, especially if the machine is a bit older. There is no setting to change that as far as I know

Comment: @X_841 That should probably be an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This sounds like normal behavior to me**, especially if the machine is a bit older.

As far as I know, there is **no** setting you can change to speed this up.

---

I can confirm that on a solid 2017 15" MBP there is a ~0.5 seconds "wait" time after hitting `enter` and the screen unlocking. But this not only varies from machine to machine, but especially from the programs that are running and if you have multiple monitors connected.

---

What you could try, but IMO is not worth it, make a clean install (preferably on an external SSD) with just one sample user with no other programs installed and check if you still have the delay.

- If the answer is yes, then it's definitely normal behavior
- If the answer is no, you might want to look into programs that are continuously running in the background, which could impact general performance.

In general though, I suspect investigating this (IMO) non-issue will take you more time than "waiting" one second every unlock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @X_841! Sorry, I haven't logged on recently so I couldn't see this until now